# Codeigniter - autoloading models with aliases

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, alias, autoload

When I manually load models in `codeigniter` I can specify an alias like so:

```
$this->load->model("user_model","user"); //user is an alias to user_model
$this->user->getProfile(); //use the alias to refer to the actual model
```

Some of these models are being extensively used in my application and so I decided to autoload them using `autoload.php`. I know I can load them so:

```
$autoload['model'] = array("user_model","another_model");
```

However they are referenced all over with their aliases. I want to load them with existing alias name so that the current code is not disturbed.

I guess I can have some code like this in an autoloaded helper maybe:

```
$ci= &get_instance();
$ci->user = $ci->user_model;
```

But what I wanted to check is, can I load model with alias name while autoloading?

Answer (score 3):

yes you can create same alias in in autoload pass as an array try but not possiable with only alias you can create same alias as auto loading time.

```
$autoload['model'] = array(array('users_model', 'users'), array('an_model', 'an'), 'other_model');
```

or try

```
$autoload['model'] = array(array('users_model', 'users', FALSE));
```

For more :- https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/2117

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/110977/#560168

Comment: I am not sure it has been implemented. I tried both ways `$autoload['model'] = array(array('users_model', 'users'));` and `$autoload['model'] = array(array("user_model" => "users")); `

Comment: @RakeshSharma it is available in `3.0-dev` version (i haven't tested) but its not in `2.2.0`

Comment: I have tested on 2.x and it's not working. But you can implement your ci, check out https://github.com/nonchip/CodeIgniter/commit/b07f700206fa58214bfeafb2ebfa7a7c2b1abb50

Answer (score 1):

For CodeIgniter 2.x this is not possible in autoloading, but you can do it by extending the default controller. Create a file `MY_Controller.php` in the `application/core` directory, with this code:

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Example_model', 'alias');
    }
}
```

Of course, replace `Example_model` and `alias` with your appropriate model and desired alias.

Then change your controllers to extend `MY_Controller` instead of `CI_Controller`. Now you can use `$this->alias->whatever()` in any Controller.